# find XML node based on element value when multiples may be present

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xmllint

```
var xmlData:XML = XML(<data>
    <item>
        <type atr="a">AAA</type>
        <type atr="b">BBB</type>
    </item>
    <item>
        <type atr="c">CCC</type>
    </item>
</data>);


trace(xmlData.item.(type=='AAA')); // does not work
trace(xmlData.item.(type=='CCC')); // works
trace(xmlData.item.type.(@atr=='a').parent()); // works
trace(xmlData.item.type.(@atr=='c').parent()); // works
```

It seems that I cannot get a node based on its value when siblings are present, unless I use attributes.

Is there a way to retrieve item based on the value when there is an unknown amount of elements, without looping manually or using attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [XMLList/contains](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html#contains()):

```
trace(xmlData.item.(type.contains(<type atr="a">AAA</type>)))
// or
trace(xmlData.item.(type.contains("AAA")))
```

Comment: unfortunately this returns a *Boolean* instead of the *XMLList*

Comment: No it doesn't you probably had `xmlData.item.type.contains()` which would return a boolean, you need to put it in filter parens, `xmlData.item.(type.contains())`, then you will get back an `XMLList` that matches the query.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, mostly by randomly trying things...

```
xmlData.item.type.(child(0)=='BBB').parent();
```

or

```
xmlData.item.type.(children()=='BBB').parent();
```

Comment: This works for your example XML but is rather fragile, because it assumes `BBB` will always be the *first* child. Your prior example of `xmlData.item.type.(@atr=='a').parent()` is better.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by frist child, if it's the location, I found it doesn't matter. If it is the depth, you could use `xmlData.item.*.type.(children()=='DDD').parent()`